# Is there any way to use smart phone like a plug and play USB speaker

Tags: usb

There are some ways like using SoundWire and other streaming methods to stream the sound over the air. But I was looking for a much straight forward way to use an Android smartphone's speakers via USB (similar to what we do for USB speakers).

I searched the internet to see whether there is any solution like I'm expecting. But I couldn’t find any. Is there any way to use android smartphones as audio output devices?

Comment: You want to plug your android into a computer and have it play audio from the computer over the android speakers? You cannot simply add files to your android from your computer via USB and play them back?

Comment: When connecting, a USB device registers its type, e.g. keyboard, speaker, HDD or mouse. If the Android device can be made to show that it is a speaker, it would be possible... but I think it's unlikely. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7034/can-i-stream-video-from-pc-to-an-android-device-over-usb

Comment: @Modern, You mean transfer the file into the memory card of the Android and play that?!

Comment: Yes, exactly... that's the closest you'll get to finding your solution, I think...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

The phone would have to report as an USB audio interface. It doesn't have hardware necessary to do so and emulation is not supported and not feasible. So again, it's not possible.